# Read large Excel file with EPPlus using Async/Await C# 6.0

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

Currently in a small but important project I have to read a rather large Excel File. This is done via help of EPPlus library. Honestly this is the first time that I'm trying to use Async/Await in a real-life scenario.

Due to the fact that this application will be running on a limited number of PCs, the binaries will be shipped on the respective local PCs. The problem I am facing is that it takes quite a bit of time for the method to read the entire Excel file and the View is of course entering in a non-responding state ( obviously ).

Thus, I have tried to make the method to read the file asynchronously but it seems I have a problem with it, basically the application shuts down just like someone would close it. Running the method with the debugger works - it reads the lines and adds them to the Data Table.

Code below:

```
 public async Task<DataTable> ReadFileContent(string filePath)
        {
            var rowStart = 7;
            var columnStart = 1;
            var existingFile = new FileInfo(filePath);
            using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
            {
                var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["BOP"];
                var dt = new DataTable();

                // Compose the name of the table from:
                // - Product Type
                // - Customer
                // - Customer Project
                // * These can be found in the "CollaborationContext" sheet that is present in the ExcelFile.

                var composedName = String.Empty;
                var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                if (package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["B6"].Value.Equals("object_type"))
                {
                    dt.TableName = package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["C9"].Value + " " +
                                   package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["D9"].Value + " " +
                                   package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["E9"].Value;
                }


                    dt.TableName = package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["B9"].Value + " " + 
                                   package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["C9"].Value + " " +
                                   package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["D9"].Value;


                // Get Columns
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {

                    for (var col = columnStart; col <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column - 1; col++)
                        dt.Columns.Add(worksheet.Cells[6, col].Value.ToString());

                    // Place data into DataTable
                    for (int row = rowStart; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
                    {
                        var dr = dt.NewRow();
                        var x = 0;

                        for (var col = columnStart; col <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column - 1; col++)
                        {
                            dr[x++] = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value;
                        }
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                });

                return dt;
            } 

        }
```

The code where the method is getting called via a ButtonClick Event is:

```
  private async  void BtnReadFileContent_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var dt =  await _sourceService.ReadFileContent(filePath);
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                BtnCreateXmlFile.IsEnabled = true;
        }
```

Clearly something I am doing is wrong, the application hangs a bit and that is not the intention, I have tried to add Debug.WriteLine("test") immediately after `var dt =  await _sourceService.ReadFileContent(filePath);` and it is getting hit only after the file has been read entirely, thus the behaviour is just like it's running synchronously.

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ReadFileContent method isn't asynchronous by nature as it doesn't use any asynchronous API:s and using `await Task.Run` for asynchronous wrappers is generally considered to be a code smell: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Try to make the method synchronous:

```
public DataTable ReadFileContent(string filePath)
{
    var rowStart = 7;
    var columnStart = 1;
    var existingFile = new FileInfo(filePath);
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["BOP"];
        var dt = new DataTable();

        var composedName = String.Empty;
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        if (package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["B6"].Value.Equals("object_type"))
        {
            dt.TableName = package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["C9"].Value + " " +
                           package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["D9"].Value + " " +
                           package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["E9"].Value;
        }


        dt.TableName = package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["B9"].Value + " " +
                       package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["C9"].Value + " " +
                       package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["D9"].Value;


        for (var col = columnStart; col <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column - 1; col++)
            dt.Columns.Add(worksheet.Cells[6, col].Value.ToString());

        // Place data into DataTable
        for (int row = rowStart; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
        {
            var dr = dt.NewRow();
            var x = 0;

            for (var col = columnStart; col <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column - 1; col++)
            {
                dr[x++] = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        return dt;
    }
}
```

...and call it on a background thread:

```
private void BtnReadFileContent_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() => _sourceService.ReadFileContent(filePath)) //<- this will run on a background thread
        .ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            //...and this will run back on the UI thread once the task has finished
            dataGrid.ItemsSource = task.Result.DefaultView;
            if (task.Result.Rows.Count > 0)
                BtnCreateXmlFile.IsEnabled = true;
        }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried your approach and it seems that the GUI is not hanging anymore, it just has a little blockage when it fills the Data Grid with the Data Table. The strange thing is that I asked a colleague of mine to help me identify the problem I had with the original code that I posted - now it works. The GUI is not blocking while the Data Table is getting filled. So as far as I understood, my approach solves the issue but it's not a good practice hence the link you provided with the blog post ?

Comment: Yes, since the ReadFileContent method is not naturally-asynchronous it shouldn't be implemented using async/await. It is the the UI, i.e. the BtnReadFileContent_OnClick method, that should run it on a background thread for the sole purpose of not blocking the UI thread. The service doesn't (shouldn't) care about this.